# Bind event to ++ operator

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger an event whenever a variable is incremented. Is that possible?

```
var a = 0;

// if this variable gets incremented ++ to 1, I want to trigger an event. 
// how can I create listener for it?
```

Google didn't help.

Comment: That's not possible for primitive types. It's only possible with objects, and only if you specify another method for incrementing. What're you trying to accomplish?

Comment: A dirty, horrible, hacky and non-reliable way to do it would be to monitor the variable in a setTimeout loop

Comment: I want a private function to trigger automatically on increment of this variable.

Comment: the setTimeout thing isnt what I am looking for. I kind of figured it wont be possible, just thought no harm in asking..

Comment: I get you want a function to trigger on increment, but I'm wondering *why*. What do you hope to accomplish with that? What is the problem you're trying to solve that you think this is the best solution to?

Comment: I am not looking to solve a massive problem here. I can manually call the function while incrementing the variable as well. I just wanted to know if there is an intuitive way to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly like your example, it's not possible.

But, if the value is in an object, you could use a `setter` using `defineProperty` to know when a value is changed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Eventually, you may be able to listen to changes on objects using `Object.observe` http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/11/Respond-to-change-with-Object-observe

---

**Support for legacy browsers**

Note thought that `defineProperty` won't work on old browsers.

If you need to support old ones, you can create an interface to change object value and do what you want on the methods (like `myInt.increment()`). (This pattern is used inside Backbone, Ember and others)

Or you can do some dirty checking by running a loop (`setTimeout`) and comparing the new value with a cached old value... (This is the solution took by Angular.js)

Comment: I added comment for legacy support if that's what your looking for.